# Preferred way to specify operation timeout

Tags: rxandroidble

What would be the recommended way of specifying a timeout for a connection or operation? Currently I use:

```
ConnectionObservable = mDevice
                .establishConnection(mRxAppCompatActivity, false)
                .timeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

But I get the impression that occasionally the subsequent automatic closing and disconnecting of the gatt is not always done properly, as I sometimes have trouble reconnecting to the same device after that.

Would something like

```
.takeUntil(disconnectTrigger)
```

with disconnectTrigger.onNext() being triggered manually after the timeout be more recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.establishConnection()` function when called with `autoConnect = false` will automatically fail after about 30 seconds.

Both options for disconnecting are equally acceptable. Usage of a particular solution is depending on the use-case in my opinion.

Note that those timeouts will be not affect much the operations that are already started - only exception is the connection operation can be cancelled but this functionality was merged into the `master` branch recently. (https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/commit/604853c4f39c5e8a19e02415c50b547b0befd0e7) The operations that are not yet processed will be removed from the operations queue.

I think that you may be suffering from a broken disconnection mechanism (it's hard to be sure with no logs). There is already a bug for this issue here: https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/63

Best Regards